# Android Studio Couldnt build the project. Getting these Errors

Tags: android, android-studio

[image] Getting these errors in the image. Tried with all the solutions available. None of them helped me. Looking forward for some help

Comment: Any specific libraries you're using in your project?

Comment: Yes, I'm using betterpickers and filechooser library

Answer (score 0):

- Delete Build folder
- clean project
- rebuild project